# Typescript conditional return type with default argument value

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make a function return a conditional type based on the argument value but with a default value for the argument :

```
function myFunc<T extends boolean>(myBoolean: T = true): T extends true 
       ? string 
       : number {
       return  myBoolean ? 'string' : 1
    }
```

this throws an error `Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'true' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'boolean'.`

I don't understand this error, since `T` is a boolean how come I can't assign `true` to it ?

I tried another approach with function overloads :

```
function myFunc(myBool: true): string
function myFunc(myBool: false): number
function myFunc(myBool = true) {
       return  myBool ? 'string' : 1
    }

myFunc()
```

but now typescript won't let me call `myFunc()` with no argument (even though it has a default value) and the first overload has an error `This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.`

Is it even possible to do what I'm trying to achieve here in typescript and if son how ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your overload approach should work. You can make the parameter optional for the `true` overload:

```
function myFunc(myBool?: true): string
function myFunc(myBool: false): number
function myFunc(myBool = true): string | number {
    return  myBool ? 'string' : 1
    }

myFunc()
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, I didn't know I needed to declare my argument as optional, thanks for the help !

Comment: This is because the implementation signature - that is, the third `myFunc` declaration in this case (the one that's not an overload) - can't be seen from the outside. So TS only looks at the two overloads and, without the `?`, doesn't see the param as optional. More here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#overload-signatures-and-the-implementation-signature

Answer (score 2):

T is not `boolean`, it is a subtype of `boolean`.

Consider a more general example:

```
type T0 = { foo: string; };
declare function useFoo<T extends foo>(arg: T = { foo: 'bar' });
```

This will fail too, because a valid T can also be `{ foo: string; bar: number; }` (a subtype of `T0`), which the default argument is not assignable to.

Default arguments and generics usually don't go hand-by-hand because of this, and you're likely better off with overloading, like in [Titian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57057782/871050).