# Typescript - how to do a conditional return type based on optional boolean parameters with a default values

Tags: typescript, default-parameters, conditional-types

I am converting some existing JS code into TS, and we've used a pattern I can't figure out how to express correctly with typescript :

```js
function getVehicles({
    brandFields = false,
    ownerFields = false,
    maintenanceFields = false
} = {}) {
    // building and executing some SQL
}
```

Our repositories rely heavily on this kind of pattern, where we put the data that's costly to fetch behind a flag, and one function can have several of these flags.

Now, trying to type the different parts of the returned value is a bit of work, but it works out nicely :

```js
type Vehicle = { id: dbId, manufactureDate: Date, color: string }
type VehicleBrand = { brandName: string, brandCountry: string }
type VehicleOwner = { owner: Person }
type VehicleMaintenance = { maintenance: { date: Date, place: string, operation: string } [} }

function getVehicles({
    brandFields = false,
    ownerFields = false,
    maintenanceFields = false
} = {}): (Vehicle & VehicleBrand & VehicleOwner & VehicleMaintenance) [] {
    // building and executing some SQL
}
```

But I want to make the return type more precise. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57057697/typescript-conditional-return-type-with-default-argument-value) suggest doing overloads, but it wouldn't be practical in this case due to the numbers of permutations.

So I think the only option left for me is to use generics and conditional types, with something along the lines of :

```js
// With only one parameter for simplicity
function getVehicles<
    Brand extends boolean
>({
    brandFields: Brand = false
} = {}): (
    Vehicle &
    (Brand extends true ? VehicleBrand : {})
) [] {
    // building and executing some SQL
}
```

But I haven't found a way to make typescript happy while returning the narrowest type possible in all situations.

```js
getVehicles()                         // should return Vehicle
getVehicles({ brandFields: false })   // should return Vehicle
getVehicles({ brandFields: true })    // should return Vehicle & VehicleBrand
getVehicles({ brandFields: boolean }) // should return Vehicle & (VehicleBrand | {})
```

The closest I've come is with this signature, but it is too lax :

```js
function getVehicles<
    Brand extends boolean
>({
    brandFields: Brand | false = false // <-- union to avoid an error ...
} = {}): (
    Vehicle &
    (Brand extends true ? VehicleBrand : {})
) [] {
    // building and executing some SQL
}

getVehicles({ brandFields: true }) // but returns Vehicle & (VehicleBrand | {}) in this case
```

Is this even achievable with the current limitation of typescript ?

Comment: I'm not sure how full-featured you need this to be.  From purely a type system perspective (and not worrying about how the implementation will be written), does [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9Ad9N) work for you?  It's extendible (you can add more option fields) and it produces what I think of as reasonable output types (the properties in each property group are either all present or all absent; the type `{}` does not imply absence of a key `foo` the way that `{foo?: never}` does).  If you like this I can write up an answer; otherwise let me know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), like this:

```
type Vehicle<O extends OptionsFlags> = VehicleBase &
  (O extends { brandFields: true }
    ? VehicleBrand
    : O extends { brandFields: false | undefined }
    ? {}
    : VehicleBrand | {}) &
  (O extends { ownerFields: true }
    ? VehicleOwner
    : O extends { ownerFields: false | undefined }
    ? {}
    : VehicleOwner | {}) &
  (O extends { maintenanceFields: true }
    ? VehicleMaintenance
    : O extends { maintenanceFields: false | undefined }
    ? {}
    : VehicleMaintenance | {});

interface OptionsFlags {
  brandFields?: boolean;
  ownerFields?: boolean;
  maintenanceFields?: boolean;
}

interface VehicleBase {
  id: dbId;
  manufactureDate: Date;
  color: string;
}
interface VehicleBrand {
  brandName: string;
  brandCountry: string;
}
interface VehicleOwner {
  owner: Person;
}
interface VehicleMaintenance {
  maintenance: { date: Date; place: string; operation: string }[];
}

function getVehicles<O extends OptionsFlags>({
  brandFields = false,
  ownerFields = false,
  maintenanceFields = false,
}: O = {} as O): Vehicle<O>[] {
  // ...
}

getVehicles({ brandFields: true }) // return type is Vehicle<{ brandFields: true }>[]
```

**However...**

Depending on how you are using this, you may find it more helpful to define your `Vehicle` type like this, which allow each `Vehicle` subtype to resolve to a single interface that may have optional properties:

```
type Vehicle<O extends OptionsFlags> = VehicleBase &
  (O extends { brandFields: true }
    ? VehicleBrand
    : O extends { brandFields: false | undefined }
    ? {}
    : Partial<VehicleBrand>) &
  (O extends { ownerFields: true }
    ? VehicleOwner
    : O extends { ownerFields: false | undefined }
    ? {}
    : Partial<VehicleOwner>) &
  (O extends { maintenanceFields: true }
    ? VehicleMaintenance
    : O extends { maintenanceFields: false | undefined }
    ? {}
    : Partial<VehicleMaintenance>);
```

`Vehicle<{ brandFields: boolean }>` would then be equivalent to:

```
{
  id: dbId;
  manufactureDate: Date;
  color: string;
  brandName?: string;
  brandCountry?: string;
}
```